# Does the mean-value theorem hold for $f(x)=x^{s}$ with $s$ complex?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

This is a basic question from Stein and Shakarchi's book *Complex Analysis*.

Let $s$ be a fixed complex number with $\operatorname{Re}(s)>0$ and $f(x)=x^{-s}$ be a function from $[n,n+1]$ to $\mathbb{C}$ where $n$ is a positive integer. On page 173, it states that one can apply the mean value theorem to $f$ to obtain the inequality $$\left|\frac{1}{n^{s}}-\frac{1}{x^{s}}\right|\leq\frac{|s|}{n^{s+1}}$$ whenever $n\leq x\leq n+1$.

I am confused because $f$ is a complex valued function so the mean-value theorem would give two possibly different values $c_1$ and $c_2$ in $(n,x)$ such that $$\operatorname{Re}(f^{\prime}(c_1))+i\operatorname{Im}(f^{\prime}(c_2))=\frac{f(x)-f(n)}{x-n}$$ and so one cannot deduce the above inequality.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\leq \frac{|s|}{n^{\operatorname{Re}(s)+1}}$?

Comment: You can argue as follows: $$
\left| {\frac{1}{{n^s }} - \frac{1}{{x^s }}} \right| = \left| {\int_n^x {\frac{{ - s}}{{t^{s + 1} }}dt} } \right| \le \int_n^x {\frac{{\left| s \right|}}{{t^{{\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} (s) + 1} }}dt}  \le \frac{{\left| s \right|}}{{n^{{\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} (s) + 1} }}\int_n^x { dt }  \le \frac{{\left| s \right|}}{{n^{{\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} (s) + 1} }}.
$$ if $n\le  x \le n+1$.

Comment: @Gary yes you are right- s should be Re(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean value theorem you can use is the fundamental theorem of calculus: For $f \in C^1([n, x], \mathbb{R}^d)$,
$$f(x) - f(n) = \int_{0}^{1}f'(n + t(x - n))(x - n)\,dt = \int_{0}^{1}f'(n + t(x - n))\,dt(x - n).$$
Here we take $d = 2$ and use $\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{C}$.